# Groups within a certain OU that a user is part of

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the name of a user, and I need to find all the groups that this user is a part of - but only those groups which are within a certain OU.

How do I do this? I know that: `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet 
finds all the groups that the user is a part of, but I have no idea how to filter this down to the specific OU, as none of the options seem to be helping.

Alternatively, any other way of doing this would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow! Show us some code that you have attempted, and how you used it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Where-Object` for the `DistinguishedName` Path

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity user | 
Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -match 'OU=SubOU,OU=MainOU,DC=Domain,DC=local'}
```

Comment: Agreed, although you might want to `[regex]::Escape('OU=SubOU,OU=MainOU,DC=Domain,DC=local')`